# Rsync just structure and specified folders

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a file structure as follows.

```
                     Sites
    --------------------------------------
    |                  |                 | 
    |                  |                 | 
    |                  |                 |
  Site 1              Site 2             Site3
 /      \            /     \            /     \
.git  dirX        .git    dirY        .git   dirZ
         |                  |                  |
         Config            Config            Config
```

I want to copy over the folder structure, the .git and its contents, and the config only. I have tried using rsync with include and exclude arguments like so but with no luck. The command completes immediately

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude='*' --include='*/.git' --include='*/Config'  Sites/ newDIR/
```

Comment: Why would you not just `git clone` the repositories?

Comment: There are around 40 directories in total so time is one reason. I would also need to setup the config for each repository if I used git clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use rsync together with the "declare" command -> Works like a charm!!!
Everything in the declared dirs gets sync'd recursively.

```
declare -a DIRS=("/etc /home /mnt /root /usr /var") # Which dirs to sync
sudo rsync -zaP $DIRS user@host:/path/to/folder --delete
```

For the exclude... I saw a working solution, which looked similar to this:

```
rsync -arvzP --exclude=.ccache --exclude=build source dest
```

## Multiple excludes at once -> this should work!

Maybe this helps...